# Statements to Predicates and Quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

"There is a student in this class who has taken every course offered by one of the departments in this school." I need to express this is predicates and quantifiers.

Can someone check my answer?  I set $ x = student, y = course, z = department$. So I let $S(x,y)$ be "Student $x$ is in course $y$". And $T(y,z)$ be "Course $y$ is in department $z$".
Therefore:
$\exists x \forall y \exists z S(x,y) \land T(y,z)$

Thanks,
Extreme112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes that $y$ could be a value thats not in the department, so we need an implication here. Let $U(x, y)$ denote that $x$ has taken $y$.

I would say, where $c$ is a particular class,

$\exists x : S(x, c) \land [\forall y : (\exists z : T(y,z)) \implies U(x, y)]$

That is, there exists $x$ such that $x$ is taking class $c$ forall $y$, if $y$ is offered by some department $z$, then $x$ is taking $y$.

Also note that if $x$ is taking class $c$ implies that $x$ has not taken $c$ then the answer is clearly "False".

Answer (score 0):

> "There is a student in this class who has taken every course offered by one of the departments in this school."

The particular entities are: this class $c$, this school $s$

The quantified entities are: one student $\exists x$, all courses $\forall y$, one department $\exists z$.

The predicates (or relations) are:

- $C(c,x):$ student $x$ is in this class $c$.
- $D(s,z):$ department $z$ belongs to this school $s$.
- $O(z,y):$ course $y$ is offered by department $z$.
- $T(x,y):$ course $y$ is taken by student $x$.

Then we translate the sentence as:

$$\exists x\, \Bigl(C(c,x)\wedge \exists z\, \bigl(D(s,z)\wedge \forall y\, (O(z,y)\to T(x,y))\bigr)\Bigr)$$

**Note:** This is interpreting the sentence to mean taking all of the courses that *one* (specific, unspecified) of the departments offers, rather than all of the courses that *any* of the departments offers.    The later would be:

$$\exists x\, \Bigl(C(c,x)\wedge \forall y\,\bigl(\exists z\, \bigl(D(s,z)\wedge O(z,y)\to T(x,y)\bigr)\bigr)\Bigr)$$

---

cf "All items on one of the pages of the menu" vs "All items on any of the pages of the menu"

$\exists p\, \forall i\,( p\in m\wedge i\in p\to T(i) )$ vs $\forall i\, \exists p\, (p\in m\wedge i\in p\to T(i) )$